# Best way to implement Table Per Hierarchy Inheritance in EF Core, ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

During the development of my website I've decided to use a base class and derive 2 others from that.

My base class is

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gendre { get; set; }
    public string CityOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string ProvinceOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string FiscalCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string AdditionaInfos { get; set; }

    public string CountryOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that I did NOT use any ID in my base class. Perhaps already a mistake. This is due to the fact that I have added the base class in a second step and I had assigned already before the IDs to the derived classes.

The other derived classes are:

```
public class Loaner : Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int AID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A> A{ get; set; }

    // user ID from AspNetUser table
    public string OwnerID { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Client : Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string TypeOfLocator { get; set; } 
    public bool IsRegistered { get; set; } = false;
    public bool TakeDataFromRegistration { get; set; } = false;
    public bool WantsToBeContactedByEmail { get; set; } = false;

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }

}
```

My DbContext looks like that:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }


    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loaner> Loaners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Address{ get; set; }

}
```

Now, how can I best implemet TPH, knowing that I do not have an ID in my base class?
My problem is that the IDs of the derived classes are already extensively used in the rest of my website.

I had a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-2.0), but this approach requires having the ID on the base class.
Do I really have to Create and customize the migration code? Or is it sufficient to use fluent API like described [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Removing the ID from the derived classes and putting it into base class should not be a problem. But *"the IDs of the derived classes are already extensively used in the rest of my website"* makes me think that probably it's too late for TPH - TPH is a single table while as I read it you already have separate tables. And duplicate Ids. So consolidating them in a single table, especially if there are FKs referencing them is not trivial task and would require you writing the whole logic manually with SQL.

Comment: What I don't really understand is if TPH is really an advantage or not. I'm still disigning my website; changing the structure will be hard work, I know, but if it is necessary I will do it. If I implement TPH, how can I then reference a Client's ID or Loaner's ID? Does it turn out to get much more complicated?